# Best way to link data rows in the same table

Tags: mysql, database-design

In this example I have a table called "Zones"

```
create table stk_zones (
    ZoneId int not null auto_increment,
    Primary Key (ZoneId),
    ZoneName varchar(255),
    Height int,
    Width int,
    Description varchar(255)
);
```

Inside this zones table I add a few records:

```
insert into stk_zones (ZoneName, Height, Width, Description)
values ('Zone A', 100, 200, 'First Zone!'), ('Zone B', 50, 50, 'Second Zone!'), ('Zone C', 50, 100, 'Third Zone!');
```

What would be the best way to show that Zone B is nested inside of Zone A?
They share the same properties so I want to keep them in the same table.

Would the best option be a secondary table, something like:

```
create table stk_zone_relations (
    ZoneRelationId int not null auto_increment,
    Primary Key (ZoneRelationId),
    ParentZoneId int,
    Foreign Key (ParentZoneId) references stk_zones (ZoneId),
    ChildZoneId int,
    Foreign Key (ChildZoneId) references stk_zones (ZoneId)
);
```

Not sure proper principals in this sort of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a zone can have only one parent, then you have a many:one relationship.  That is implemented with just `ParentId` linking to `ZibeId`.

If you have zones that belong to multiple other zones (overlapping?), then it sounds more like "many:many".  That requires an extra table with 2 columns - each being a `ZoneId`.  See [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for index advice.

Comment: In this case the Zone can have a parent, or no parent. So I think the Many-To-Many would be the case. I think the part I am thrown off is with the Many-To-Many table having the relationship just be coming from the single table.

Comment: @Travis "*the Zone can have a parent, or no parent. So I think the Many-To-Many would be the case*" - No this would be Zero-Or-One-To-Many which can be implicitly simplified by saying One-To-Many. You can accomplish your goal with a nullable foreign key `ParentZoneId` field in your `Zones` table, like Rick mentions.

Comment: Then in case the zone can be in multiple parents, would require a second table for a Many-To-Many? @J.D.

Comment: @Travis Yes, if the same zone can have multiple parents, then it would be a many-to-many relationship and need a separate table. But your previous comment said zero or one parent.

Comment: Yup, just trying to ask questions about other scenarios. Thank you.

Comment: 1:many with lack of a parent can be represented by NULL (and still involve only 1 table).  That is, I agree with J.D.